# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException:cannot find any provider supporting AES

Tags: java, encryption

I have strucked at this issue  java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: cannot find any provider supporting AES .

```
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
```

I am using  jdk1.6.0_45 64 bit . Does version is the problem for this or any other. Before I got an error "illegal key size or default parameters java" and then it was resolved with by adding these things in environmental variables. I had set JAVA_HOME & classpath with local_policy & US_export_policy .

Can any help me out of this issue.

Comment: Run `for ( Provider provider : Security.getProviders() ) { System.out.println( provider ); }` to check which providers are detected by your JVM. Add another inner cycle `if ( "Cipher".equals( service.getType() ) ) { System.out.println( service ); }` to check which ciphers are still present. It seems that somehow you managed to disable SunJCE provider.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this issue.. The thing we have to do is. We should add the driver in the respective server folders. I am using Jboss server. In JBoss server we have to add bouncy castle jar file in jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\lib.